# Jacobian Transformation p.d.f

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables with joint p.d.f.
>
> $$f(x,y) = e^{-y},\,\, 0<x<y <\infty$$
>
> (a) Find the joint p.d.f. of $U=X+Y$ and $V=X$. Be sure to specify the support of $(U,V)$.
>
> (b)  Find the marginal p.d.f. of $U$ and the marginal p.d.f. of $V$. Be sure to specify their support.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with this question. So far, I have gotten that the support for $U$ and $V$ is $0<v<u<\infty$, the Jacobean matrix has determinant $-1$ and that the joint p.d.f for part a) is $e^{v-u}$ but this p.d.f doesn't make sense when I try to find the marginals. Could someone help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: To start, maybe you or @A.D should repair the TeX code for your PDF. When something is botched in an edit, it is difficult to discern original intent. Just a guess, but check the limits on integrals, or tell us what limits you used.

Comment: The support of (U,V) is not the set of (u,v) such that u>v>0 since U>2V almost surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I checked if it is indeed a density $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^ye^{-y}dxdy=1$$

and $X,Y$ are not independent.So I proceeded as you already did

$(1)U=g_1(X,Y)=X+Y$ and $(2)V=g_2(X,Y)=X$ then $J=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}=-1$ hence $|J|^{-1}=1$

You know that $Y=U-V$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$
$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(g_1^{-1}(u,v),g_2^{-1}(u,v))|J|=e^{v-u}$$

You know that $$0<x<y\iff0<v<u-v\iff0<2v<u$$
hence
$$f_U(u)=\int_0^{u/2} e^{v-u}dv=(e^{-u/2}-e^{-u})\,I_{[0,\infty)}(u)$$
$$f_V(v)=\int_{2v}^\infty e^{v-u}du=e^{-v}I_{[0,\infty)}(v)$$

Comment: The density of V cannot depend on some parameter u. Also, see my comment to the question.

Comment: @Did I was trying something here, and to me it seems $u>0$ and $v>0$, it's wrong?

Comment: But now your f_V is not a density.

Comment: @Did I think now it's fine.

Comment: The densities of $U$ and $V$ are correct now (but it is not clear to me what the notation $f_{X,Y}^{-1}(u,v)$ is referring to).

Comment: @Did I wrote this way because I no longer remember the standard way, I edited, but correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Seems perfect to me. +1.